# PHP json validation

Tags: c#, php, json

I want to creat php file call a json to validate isvalidkey false like that: 
file 1 or file 2

Bboth of them must determined by 2 different files name.

Like file 1 “aaa”. file 2 “bbb”  and both of them has settings
 *purchasecode, serverkey, domain, file*

If file 1 must check settings correct if isvalidkey is true so access and get instance if not return error

Example:

- if file1 = file aaa and settings are validated so return url; if file not correct so error.
- if file correct and purchacecode is false so error code not valid.
- if file = aaa and codepurchase valid and empty domain so error domain not valid
- if file = aaa and codepurchase valid valid domain and serverkey is not valid so error servername is not valid.

Same thing for file 2

json:

```
{
  "title": "CurrentInstance",
  "type": "object",
  "Settings": {
    "domain": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "purchase_code": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "UserID": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "server_key": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "application_Type": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "domain", "purchase_code", "server_key"
  ]
}
```

my file php

```
<?php

$data = '{"domain":"https://www.MyProjet.com","purchase_code":"XXXXXXXXXXXX","server_key":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}';

$validator = new JsonSchema\validator;
$validator->validate($data, (object)['$ref' => 'file://' . realpath('file.json')]);

$validator->IsValidKey()
```

my project is on C# this is the class

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyProject_API.Classes.Global;

namespace MyProject_API
{
  public class Current
  {
    public bool IsValidKey = true;
    private static Current currentInstance;
    public string Access_token;

    private Current()
    {
    }

    public string ServerKey { get; set; } = "";

    public string UserID { get; set; }

    public string SetConnectionType { get; set; }

    public IMethods Function { get; set; }

    public static Current CurrentInstance
    {
      get
      {
        if (Current.currentInstance == null)
          Current.currentInstance = new Current();
        return Current.currentInstance;
      }
    }

    public static void DisposeInstance()
    {
      if (Current.currentInstance == null)
        return;
      Current.currentInstance = (Current) null;
    }

    public void SetWebsiteURL(string website, string serverkey)
    {
      try
      {
        this.Function = new IMethods();
        this.Function.CounterofError = 5;
        Client.WebsiteUrl = website;
        Current.CurrentInstance.ServerKey = serverkey;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine((object) ex);
      }
    }

    public static async Task<JObject> GetMyProject_Settings(string PurchaseCode, string Website, string ServerKey, string application_Type)
    {
      try
      {
        string PersonalFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string filePathFile1 = Path.Combine(PersonalFolder, Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("d2FlbA=="));
        string filePathFile2 = Path.Combine(PersonalFolder, Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("d3Q="));
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (RemoteCertificateValidationCallback) ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
        Current.CurrentInstance.ServerKey = ServerKey;
        if (application_Type == "AndroidFile1")
        {
          if (Directory.Exists(filePathFile1))
            throw new Exception(Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("eW91IGhhdmUgYmVlbiBibG9ja2Vk"));
        }
        else if (application_Type == "AndroidFile2" && Directory.Exists(filePathFile2))
          throw new Exception(Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("eW91IGhhdmUgYmVlbiBibG9ja2Vk"));
        if ((uint) Current.CurrentInstance.Function.CounterofError > 0U)
        {
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Client.WebsiteUrl))
            throw new Exception(Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("WW91ciB3ZWJzaXRlIFVSTCBpcyBFbXB0eQ=="));
          using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
          {
            FormUrlEncodedContent SiteValues = new FormUrlEncodedContent((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>) new KeyValuePair<string, string>[2]
            {
              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("purchase_code", PurchaseCode),
              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("domain", Website)
            });
            using (HttpClient clientSite = new HttpClient())
            {
              HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage1 = await clientSite.PostAsync("http://app.MyProject.com/ here where php and json are needed", (HttpContent) SiteValues);
              HttpResponseMessage responseSite = httpResponseMessage1;
              httpResponseMessage1 = (HttpResponseMessage) null;
              responseSite.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
              string str1 = await responseSite.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
              string json = str1;
              str1 = (string) null;
              SiteObject data = (SiteObject) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SiteObject>(json);
              if (!(data.Status == "200"))
                throw new Exception(data.Message);
              FormUrlEncodedContent SettingsValues = new FormUrlEncodedContent((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>) new KeyValuePair<string, string>[1]
              {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("server_key", ServerKey)
              });
              HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage2 = await client.PostAsync(Current.URLS.UrlInstance.API_Get_Site_Settings, (HttpContent) SettingsValues);
              HttpResponseMessage responseSettings = httpResponseMessage2;
              httpResponseMessage2 = (HttpResponseMessage) null;
              responseSettings.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
              string str2 = await responseSettings.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
              string jsonSettings = str2;
              str2 = (string) null;
              Dictionary<string, object> dataSettings = (Dictionary<string, object>) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonSettings);
              string apiStatusSettings = dataSettings["api_status"].ToString();
              if (apiStatusSettings == "200")
              {
                JObject settings = JObject.FromObject(dataSettings["config"]);
                if (application_Type == "AndroidFile1")
                {
                  if (ServerKey == ((object) settings.get_Item("widnows_app_api_key")).ToString())
                  {
                    if (((object) settings.get_Item(Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("Zm9vdGVyX2JhY2tncm91bmQ="))).ToString() != "#aaa")
                    {
                      Current.CurrentInstance.IsValidKey = false;
                      --Current.CurrentInstance.Function.CounterofError;
                      if (Current.CurrentInstance.Function.CounterofError == 0)
                        throw new Exception(Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("WW91ciBhcHBsaWNhdGlvbiBpcyBiYW5uZWQgZnJvbSB1c2UgLCBZb3UgY2Fubm90IGFueW1vcmUgdXNlIGl0IG9uIHlvdXIgZG9tYWluIG5hbWUgDQpDb250YWN0IHRoZSBTdXBwb3J0IHRlYW0gb3IgYnV5IHRoZSBsaWNlbnNlIA=="));
                      if (Current.CurrentInstance.Function.CounterofError == 1)
                        throw new Exception(Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("V2FybmluZyEhIExhc3QgZmFpbCBhbmQgYXR0ZW1wdCBhbmQgeW91ciBkb21haW4gbmFtZSB3aWxsIGJlIGJsb2NrZWQgZnJvbSB1c2U="));
                      throw new Exception(Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("VmVyaWZ5IHlvdXIgYXBwbGljYXRpb24gZnJvbSB5b3VyIGFkbWluIHBhbmVsIHlvdSBoYXZlIHN0aWxsIA==") + (object) Current.CurrentInstance.Function.CounterofError + " " + Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("QXR0ZW1wdHM="));
                    }
                    Current.CurrentInstance.IsValidKey = true;
                    return settings;
                  }
                  Current.CurrentInstance.IsValidKey = false;
                  throw new Exception(Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("U2VydmVyIGtleSBpcyBpbmNvcnJlY3Q="));
                }
                if (application_Type == "AndroidFile2")
                {
                  if (ServerKey == ((object) settings.get_Item("widnows_app_api_key")).ToString())
                  {
                    if (((object) settings.get_Item(Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("Zm9vdGVyX2JhY2tncm91bmRfbg=="))).ToString() != "#aaa")
                    {
                      Current.CurrentInstance.IsValidKey = false;
                      --Current.CurrentInstance.Function.CounterofError;
                      if (Current.CurrentInstance.Function.CounterofError == 0)
                        throw new Exception(Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("WW91ciBhcHBsaWNhdGlvbiBpcyBiYW5uZWQgZnJvbSB1c2UgLCBZb3UgY2Fubm90IGFueW1vcmUgdXNlIGl0IG9uIHlvdXIgZG9tYWluIG5hbWUgDQpDb250YWN0IHRoZSBTdXBwb3J0IHRlYW0gb3IgYnV5IHRoZSBsaWNlbnNlIA=="));
                      if (Current.CurrentInstance.Function.CounterofError == 1)
                        throw new Exception(Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("V2FybmluZyEhIExhc3QgZmFpbCBhbmQgYXR0ZW1wdCBhbmQgeW91ciBkb21haW4gbmFtZSB3aWxsIGJlIGJsb2NrZWQgZnJvbSB1c2U="));
                      throw new Exception(Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("VmVyaWZ5IHlvdXIgYXBwbGljYXRpb24gZnJvbSB5b3VyIGFkbWluIHBhbmVsIHlvdSBoYXZlIHN0aWxsIA==") + (object) Current.CurrentInstance.Function.CounterofError + " " + Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("QXR0ZW1wdHM="));
                    }
                    Current.CurrentInstance.IsValidKey = true;
                    return settings;
                  }
                  Current.CurrentInstance.IsValidKey = false;
                  throw new Exception(Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("U2VydmVyIGtleSBpcyBpbmNvcnJlY3Q="));
                }
                Current.CurrentInstance.IsValidKey = true;
                return settings;
              }
              Current.CurrentInstance.IsValidKey = false;
              JObject settings1 = JObject.FromObject(dataSettings["errors"]);
              string ErrorMsg = ((object) settings1.get_Item("error_text")).ToString();
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMsg))
                throw new Exception(ErrorMsg);
              return (JObject) null;
            }
          }
        }
        else
        {
          Current.CurrentInstance.IsValidKey = false;
          if (application_Type == "AndroidFile1")
          {
            if (!Directory.Exists(filePathFile1))
              Directory.CreateDirectory(filePathFile1);
          }
          else if (application_Type == "AndroidFile2" && !Directory.Exists(filePathFile2))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(filePathFile2);
          throw new Exception(Current.CurrentInstance.Function.Binarydata("eW91IGhhdmUgYmVlbiBibG9ja2Vk"));
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Current.CurrentInstance.IsValidKey = false;
        Console.WriteLine((object) ex);
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
      }
    }
 public class URLS
    {
        ....


         private URLS()
      {
      }

      public static Current.URLS UrlInstance
      {
        get
        {
          if (Current.URLS.urlInstance == null)
            Current.URLS.urlInstance = new Current.URLS();
          return Current.URLS.urlInstance;
        }
      }

      public static void DisposeInstance()
      {
        if (Current.URLS.urlInstance == null)
          return;
        Current.URLS.urlInstance = (Current.URLS) null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: People on SO are more likely to assist if you put a little effort into it, like show your code, where it fails, etc.  Otherwise your post would look like you are wanting SO members to write your code for you. Just not gonna happen here.

Comment: i added some code for helping me